# how can I write a string like: <space> in html text

Tags: html

I have many pages of html and I want to write a text like this `'DOM<space>LUNCH'`.
But when I write the text like above then it showing space instead of  in browser,
because browser understand  as a html tag and print is as a space. :
Like this:`'DOM LUNCH'`.

I used this also `'DOM \<space\> LUNCH'`,so that it will ignore the next letter,but noting goes right.

Please tell me how can I write a string in html like this:`'DOM<space>LUNCH'`

Even I am not able to post the question as I want, because browser understand space and `<>` as space actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

`&lt;mytag&gt;`

The closing part of the tag doesn't absolutely have to be replaced however.

`&lt;mytag>`

Comment: It works.I hadn't think about that.I am happy to have an assistance from you.